# I am trying to import the following commands

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to import the following commands in Snowpark setup on Jupter notebook using scala kernel, However I get the following error for the following commands:

import org.pmml4s.model.Model
cmd11.sc:1: object pmml4s is not a member of package org
Compilation failed

package algorithms:
(console):1:1 expected end-of-input
package algorithms
^
(console):1:1 expected end-of-input
package algorithms

Comment: Not a direct solution for your issue but I would suggest to review this : https://medium.com/snowflake/from-zero-to-snowpark-in-5-minutes-72c5f8ec0b55

Comment: You could try *import _root_.org.pmml4s.model.Model cmd11.sc*. I see others had similar issues as well, see [here](https://github.com/almond-sh/almond/issues/63)

Answer (score 0):

Do not how you installed pmml4s in your Jupyter environment but if you are using the almond kernel you can get it installed by

```
import $ivy.`org.pmml4s:pmml4s_2.12:0.9.11`
```

After that you should be able to import it.